# PrimeNG - datatable: How to dynamically load columns and their fields in primeNg datatable?

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I have json list, which have some input field and some dropdown fields. now when displaying it in datatable, i want to show Input Field or Dropdown Field based on field type in my json list.

my code is

```
<p-dataTable [value]="earningList" [responsive]="true" reorderableColumns="true" [editable]="true" >
<p-column [style]="{'width':'38px', 'padding-left':'10px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
<p-column *ngFor="let column of earningColumns" [field]="column.field" [header]="column.header" [editable]="column.editable" [style]="{'width':'100px'}">

</p-column></p-dataTable>
```

This code is working and shows all data and columns, but i want to show if the field is dropdown in json list then in table it should show dropdown.

How can i do that? is if condition works here?
Thank in advance.

EDIT:
After Alex comments, i have edit my code as follow

```
<p-column *ngFor="let column of earningColumns" [field]="column.field" [header]="column.header" [editable]="column.editable" [style]="{'width':'100px'}">
<template let-col let-earnings="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
    <p-dropdown *ngIf="column.isDropdown" [style]="{'width':'100px'}" [options]="taxFrequency"></p-dropdown>
</template>
```

but it is showing dropdown with no list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is: [Templates](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/templating).
You can use these to style your cells, depending on the values of the data. In there you can use something like `*ngIf="column.isDropdown"` to display a dropdown.

Comment: I have tried with *ngIf, and it is showing dropdown, but it is not showing list for that, only blank dropdown in displayed.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the scope of `taxFrequency`. I can't tell where this resides and if you are accessing it in the right way.

Comment: taxFrequency is my json list of type SelectItem, and it is their in component. and this taxFrequency list is getting binded to dropdown if i use this in hard coded dropdown list somewhere in page.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, it works in my test project. Maybe you can create a Plunker and share your problem?

Comment: alex, i am new in plunker also, can you share your your test project on plunker, so that i can get to know if i m doing anything wrong.